Young Adult novel about a time traveller with AI and a haunted forest
The main thing I remember about this story is that the main character is a time-traveller who is travelling with a computerised representation of his sister. During the course of events, he forms a friendship with a brother and sister who find him a bit odd.
The story takes places near a woodland or forest which has a reputation for being haunted and is avoided by the townsfolk where the story takes place
I don't remember exactly how events unfold but the climax is that the trio are pursued into a forest where it turns out the reason people have seem ghosts is that themselves as the time traveller had some kind of defence mechanism that shifted them in time (or space) in a time loop and people could see their 'ghosts'.
I read the book in the mid-to-late 80's and would estimate it was written in the late 70's.
